# How to get variables from csv file one row at a time and loop the project?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm just Starting In python day 3 and trying own projects with selenium chromedriver

i'm trying to automate login and update phone number on 50 accounts but i don't know how to get username,pass,number from csv file one row at a time and loop the whole project in a  loop.  please help any advice would be great

Here is the csv file
[Csv image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcntO.png)

```
login          pass         number
username1   password-1  631-563-7224
username2   password-2  631-563-7225
username3   password-3  631-563-7226
username4   password-4  631-563-7227
username5   password-5  631-563-7228
username6   password-6  631-563-7229
username7   password-7  631-563-7230
username8   password-8  631-563-7231
username9   password-9  631-563-7232
```

And This is the code so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import os


options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,180")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?contextid=D6D1F463EB285DA7&bk=1620539399&ru=https://login.live.com/login.srf%3fcontextid%3dD6D1F463EB285DA7%26uiflavor%3dweb%26mkt%3dEN-US%26lc%3d1033%26bk%3d1620539399%26uaid%3d3e34bc362ac34e88897c544e1372a282&uiflavor=web&lic=1&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&uaid=3e34bc362ac34e88897c544e1372a282/")

#folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Create a Microsoft account']")
#folder.click()

folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='MemberName']")
name = "username1@outlook.com"
folder.send_keys("username1@outlook.com")


folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='iSignupAction']")
folder.click()
```

Thanks to @th-spt   his answered solved my Q :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'csv-example.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
print(sheet_ranges['A2'].value)
print(sheet_ranges['B2'].value)
print(sheet_ranges['C2'].value)
id1 = sheet_ranges['A2'].value
id2 = sheet_ranges['B2'].value
id3 = sheet_ranges['C2'].value

folder.send_keys(id1) #in line 20th from your code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this libs : openpyxl

Link Docs:https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

and then try to create object to keep your data from excel you read from.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'YOUR_EXCEL_FILE.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['YOUR_SHEET']
print(sheet_ranges['YOUR_CELL'].value)
id = sheet_ranges['YOUR_CELL'].value
```

and then you get the id in your .send_keys() function like this:

```
folder.send_keys(id) #in line 20th from your code
```

If this answer is not clear please feel free to comment me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. Username is in index 0,password is in index 1 and number is in index 2.

```
import csv
with open("filename.csv", "r") as f:
       reader  = csv.reader(f)
       for i in reader:
           username = i[0]
           password = i[1]
           number = i[2]
           print(username,password,number)
```

Comment: `username, password, number = i` is a bit more elegant, but indeed, use the csv reader